# How to copy a request from one workspace to another in Postman?

Tags: postman

How to copy a request from one workspace to another in Postman? The Duplicate option just creates a copy in the same workspace and collection.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to copy individual requests. You can however do it at the collection level.

If you click ... next to collection name, you'll get options to move or export.

- Selecting move will give you an option to select the target workspace.
- Selecting export will generate a json file. You can then import this json in the target workspace.

Comment: If you mean import the whole collection, I don't want to do that. I guess I just have to manually create these requests by copying and pasting their bits.

Answer (score 2):

In Postman, to move FolderA from CollectionA in WorkspaceA to CollectionB in WorkspaceB

1. Create a new collection *Temp* in WorkspaceA
2. Drag and drop FolderA to *Temp*
3. Click ... of *Temp* and select Move
4. Select the WorskspaceB and click Move Collection
5. Go to WorskspaceB.
6. Drag and drop the folder from *Temp* to the CollectionB
7. Delete *Temp* collection from WorkspaceB

You can use the same method to move a request.

Answer (score 1):

We can move the requests to other collections by drag and drop.